# Set value to h:inputHidden using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

Am trying set value to `h:inputHidden` from jquery. But am unable to do that.

Whats my mistake here? Please suggest me some solution

Here is my code

**jQuery Code :**

```
$(function() {
              $( "#slider-range-max-home" ).slider({
              range: "max",
              min: 1,
              max: 10,
              value: 2,
              slide: function( event, ui ) {
              $( "#ardHome" ).val( ui.value );
            }
           });
           $( "#ardHome" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max-home" ).slider( "value" ) );
   });
```

**XHtml Code :**

```
<b:column  col-xs="12" col-lg="6"  >
    <div id="slider-range-max-home"></div>
    <h:inputHidden id="ardHome" value="#{registrationController.selectedArdHome}"/>
</b:column>
```

Comment: that isn't html for sure.

Comment: It would be more easier to diagnose problem, if you post generated HTML.

Comment: Sorry for that. Its xhtml code

Comment: No it isn't - it's JSF. We need to see what you get when you right click in the browser and choose "view-source"

Answer (score 0):

Your ids are different: you are reading "#ardHome" and writing "#home". If you have a form outside this snippet, the input id will be concatenated with the form id. In Chrome of Firefox, try to inspect your input to see its id.